# pass string as argument

Tags: c, string

I am trying to pass string as an argument but result is always `pointer.c:13:14: error: cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int swg(char*)`

the string i want to pass in looks like

```
char * str
```

this string gets value using fgets/getline

my function lookslike this

```
int swg ( char *g){
   char *tmp;
   size_t i;
   tmp=strtok(*g,">");
   for ( i = 0 ; i < strlen ( tmp ) ; i ++ ) {
     if(tmp[i]=='A') return 0;
   }
   return 1;
  }
```

and i am calling it like this

```
int tst;
tst=swg(str)
```

i even tried using `tst=swg(&str)` but it didnt work , how can i pass string as argument then?

Comment: You are passing a pointer to pointer to string to your function swg.
Try `tst=swg(*str);`

Comment: What doesn't work mean? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line that appears incorrect to me is

```
tmp=strtok(*g,">");
```

This should be:

```
tmp=strtok(g,">");
```

The call `tst=swg(str)` appears OK.

Answer (score 0):

To simply fix the conversion mismatch, simply replace `tmp=strtok(*g,">");` by `tmp=strtok(g,">");`.

Anyways, you code appears to have other issues than this.

In order to process every token in your input string, you must call `strtok()` until there are no more tokens to be processed.

Find below an example of that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int swg(char g[])
{
   size_t i;
   char *tmp = strtok(g, ">");
   while (tmp != NULL)
   {
       for (i=0; i<strlen(tmp); i++)
           if (tmp[i] == 'A')
               return 0;
       tmp = strtok(NULL, ">");
   }
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char str_one[] = "LOREM>A>IPSUM";
    char str_two[] = "LOREM>B>IPSUM";

    printf("Test one: %d\n", swg(str_one));
    printf("Test two: %d\n", swg(str_two));

    return 0;
}
```

> **Output:**
> Test one: 0
> Test two: 1